Send message from a local website to extension using chrome api
I'm trying to send message from my webapp to my chrome extension. But it displays an error "chrome is undefined". What could be the possible reasons for that? Also, should I test these chrome api calls from the deployed website, or it should work fine on the localhost also?
This is my app folder structure:
Inside utils, there is an ActiveContext file, which handles the global state variables. Inside one of the useeffects, I'm using the chrome api as follows:
if (chrome && chrome.runtime) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage("mpfbfhdcdhcdllmgmngbhacdpojclmdc", { text: "Hello from Next.js!" }, response => {
        console.log('Response:', response);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Chrome runtime not found.');
    }

On running in local env, it always results in the error "chrome.runtime is undefined".
Below is the manifest.json of my extension:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Newboard-Extension (Local)",
  "short_name": "N-C-S",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Newboard App Chrome Extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/icons/icon16.png",
    "32": "/icons/icon32.png",
    "48": "/icons/icon48.png",
    "192": "/icons/icon192.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage","activeTab","tabs","storage","cookies","activeTab","scripting"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["index.html"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
      "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type":"module"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "https://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ]
  }

}
And I'm trying to receive the message as follows in the background.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(`Received message from ${sender.url}:`, message);
    // Process the message here
  });


Typo: the second https should be http  inside externally_connectable.
